# Adding dynamic alerts (with fixed position) using HTML5/Bootstrap and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add alerts to the top of a web page. The javascript is as follows;

```
window.onload = function () {

    var dps = []; // dataPoints

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
        title :{
            text: "Cell 1 Temperature (\xB0C)"
        },
        axisX: {
            title:"Time (seconds)",

        },
        axisY:{
            title: "Temperature (\xB0C)",
        },          
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: dps 
        }]
    });

    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 100; 
    var updateInterval = 100;
    var dataLength = 5000; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

    var updateChart = function (count) {
        count = count || 1;
        // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
            yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
            dps.push({
                x: xVal,
                y: yVal
            });
            xVal++;
        };
        if (dps.length > dataLength)
        {
            dps.shift();                
        }
        chart.render();     

        //print stuff
        document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML=yVal + "&deg;C";
    };

    // generates first set of dataPoints
    updateChart(dataLength); 

    // update chart after specified time. 
    setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);
}
```

Essentially when that yVal variable is less than -100 or greater than 100 I want to print an alert dialog to the top of the web page. I want the alert to disappear when the value goes back between -100 and 100. I also want the alert to be fixed to the top of the web page so when it does appear it remains there even if the user scrolls down.

I attempted to add the following code to the javascript:

```
if (-100>yVal>100) {
            document.getElementById("alert1").innerHTML="DANGA'";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("alert2").innerHTML="S'All GOOOD";
        }
```

and have the following alerts in the HTML:

```
    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="position: fixed" id="alert1"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-success" style="position: fixed" id="alert2"></div>
```

But there are several problems. First, once triggered these alerts never change. And to begin with these alerts are always present, there just isn't any text in them until triggered.

If someone knew a way to have these alerts appear and disappear only when desired, and when present to remain in a fixed position, that would be appreciated.

Thanks